# Inner join with 3 tables MySql

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have 3 tables (ativo, modelo, tipo) and I need get some columns of the tables (tipo and modelo).

Structure:

```
Ativo:  id_ativo,  name_ativo,  fk_tipo_atv,    fk_modelo_atv
Tipo:   id_tipo,   name_tipo
Modelo: id_modelo, name_modelo, fk_tipo_modelo
```

I need list "name - name_tipo - name_modelo"
Anyone can help me?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks research effort.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given us much to go on regarding what results you want, how the tables are linked and what you've tried but assuming that `Ativo.fk_tipo_atv` is a link to `Tipo.id_tipo` and `Ativo.fk_modelo_atv` is a link to `Modelo.id_modelo`:

```
SELECT a.name_ativo,t.name_tipo,m.name_modelo 
FROM Ativo a
INNER JOIN Tipo t ON (a.fk_tipo_atv = t.id_tipo)
INNER JOIN Modelo m ON (a.fk_modelo_atv = m.id_modelo)
```